# Best approach to change or "override" an action in a chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have a problem where I have 100+ servers where I need to make sure a particular process is running... These 100 servers are broken up into 4 different environments and I have numerous roles configured. The chef code is most basic in this case:

```
service "some_process" do
    supports :status => true
    action :start
end
```

Suppose I want to restart this process on a particular environment, node, or role. I used something like this:

```
knife ssh "name:node_name" "service some_process restart" -i id_rsa 
knife ssh "name:role_name" "service some_process restart" -i id_rsa 
knife ssh "name:environment_name" "service some_process restart" -i id_rsa
```

However this has been flagged as a security violation by my internal security team. So I have to find an alternative...

What is the best approach to temporarily change the recipe from "start" to "restart" and then manage this through individual nodes, entire environments, or even certain roles? Is there a mechanism to override the 'start' and force a 'restart' by editing the runlist and/or utilizing the attributes?

Comment: although an answer has been accepted and what you would like to achieve sounds like a poor design, your question was **whether it can be done?** -- yes, it is possible -- you can always achieve it with a branching in your recipe based on a computed variable. another way, is to use a data bag and set the value(s) in a central location, which can be retrieved during `chef-client` run. doing so with a data bag implies that you do not modify your cookbook, and there is no need to be concern with rolling out a new version of your cookbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chef is not a remote execution framework, what you are doing is the correct way to handle this (though maybe with a better SSH client like Fabric, Invoke, or Capistrano).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you have more than one recipe.  One recipe will use `action :start` the other would use `action :restart`.  You can then temporarily override the runlist if you need to force a restart.  Nonetheless, @coderanger is right.  This is not the purpose of Chef, and there are various tools which handle the situation much more gracefully.